# Ionic $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom() closes keyboard on Android

Tags: android, angularjs, keyboard, ionic-framework

After call $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom(); inside of a controller while the keyboard on Android is visible, then, the keyboard is automaticaly closed.

The keyboard should keep visible.

Anyone can help me to find out how to avoid this behavior?

A little piece of code:

```
callback_onmessage = function(message) {
    $scope.chat.push( message );
    $scope.$apply();
    $ionicScrollDelegate.scrollBottom(); //After this the keyboard is closed
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I didn't get any solution yet

Answer (score 0):

Is your input getting 'onblur'? Check whether the cursor is still in that input after the scroll happens. Using `Keyboard.disableScroll()` may prevent `onblur` from happening. As a workaround, you could open the keyboard again with `cordova.plugins.Keyboard.show`